# How do I add lens correction for my model+lens to Lensfun in Darktable?

Tags: olympus, darktable, lens-correction

- **Camera:** Olympus OMD EM-10
- **Lens:** Olympus M.Zuiko Digital 14-42mm f/3.5-5.6 EZ
- **Darktable:** 1.4.2

My raw's are showing a lot of distortion with the above lens that I try to correct using the Lens Correction module.

In that module, the message "camera/lens not found - please select manually" is displayed and no correction is available.

The [doc](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04s04.html.php) refers to the LensFun database whose current version [seems to supports](http://wilson.bronger.org/lensfun_coverage.html) my camera + lens.

How can I check which version of LensFun DT 1.4.2 supports and how can I add my camera + lens data into DT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For lensfun <= 0.2.8, you may download http://wilson.bronger.org/db/version_0.tar.bz2, and extract its contents over your old database, which usually resides in /usr/share/lensfun (clean this directory first).

For lensfun > 0.3.0, a simple "lensfun-update-data" on the command line, possibly with a "sudo", is enough.

Both methods install the current (less than 24h old) lensfun database.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But my lens is still not automatically found by DT though. But is now shown in the pull down menus when I select it manually.

Comment: Ok, just found a workaround. I edited the mil-olympus.xml file and duplicated the XML node for my lens. I then changed the <model> tag to exactly reflect the lens model reported in the raw's exif `OLYMPUS M.14-42mm F3.5-5.6 EZ`. Et voilà.

Comment: Would you mind uploaded a zipped RAW of yours at http://wilson.bronger.org/calibration so that I can fix Lensfun?

Comment: Done. So you are the guy behind http://wilson.bronger.org/ Thanks a lot man. Nice contribution to the OSS and to DT. Nice job.