# Lens correction in darktable when my lens isn't known?

Tags: distortion, darktable, lens-correction

I took some raw (CR2) photos and want to edit them in **darktable**. The focal length is quite low and the distortion high.

Usually I **correct the distortion** by using darktable's `lens correction` module which automatically chooses the right values based on the exif information. It works for DSLRs but for this very camera the values are not known.

[image: lens correction]

My question:

- What's the way to correct the distortion in darktable, if I cannot choose the right objective from the drop down menu in the *lens correction* module?
- How do I determine the values? Which values should I choose?

Comment: Related (ignoring the specific lens/body): [Darktable doesn't recognize tamron 18-270mm lens](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/83436)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Darktable doesn't recognize tamron 18-270mm lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83436/darktable-doesnt-recognize-tamron-18-270mm-lens)

Comment: That's right, but the solution of @junkyardsparkle worked perfectly and the answer to [Darktable doesn't recognize tamron 18-270mm lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83436/darktable-doesnt-recognize-tamron-18-270mm-lens) doesn't explain a workaround.

Comment: Can you please link the other question here? (mark the other as a duplicate?) Because @junkyardsparkle's answer helps a lot and is way more detailed.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tya1U6Ki5Rg - It's using the lens profiles from adobe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of right now, darktable doesn't have a very good way of doing *ad hoc* distortion correction for a lens you don't have a lensfun profile for. The following is a dirty hack that *may* be useful in cases where the barrel distortion at the wide end of a zoom is so strong that even "incorrect" correction might be an improvement...

In the lens correction module:

- Click on the top (camera) dropdown list and select *Generic* --> *Crop-factor 1.0 (Full Frame)*
- For the lens dropdown: Select *Generic* --> *Rectilinear 10-1000mm f/1.0*.
- Change the *geometry* to *fish-eye*
- Change *mode* to *distort*

Now, when you change the value in the "mm" dropdown menu, you should get different degrees of generic "defishing"; start at the largest mm values and work down the list until you find something that looks closest to correct. Clicking the circular arrow button to the right of the "scale" slider will auto-adjust the scale to the largest crop with no blank pixels.

If you're trying to correct "pincushion" distortion at the long end of a zoom, change the mode to "correct" instead of "distort".

Comment: Good info. But I believe that [lensfun 0.3.95 (development) has info for the G5 X](https://wilson.bronger.org/lensfun_coverage.html), so perhaps just an update to 0.3.95 is all that's necessary?

Comment: @scottbb Yeah, but that's been covered elsewhere, and this seemed like a good place to introduce this little workaround. ;)

Comment: @CRThaze and others: There's now a github issue regarding how to improve this situation, [here](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/1990)... if you would find the added manual controls useful, consider leaving a comment to that effect.

Comment: I had to cycle "correction method" to "only manual vignette" and then back to "Lensfun database" for "target geometry" and other relevant controls to be enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Missing lenses are probably added in the latest version of `lensfun`. The problem is that lensfun don't get updates via the packet manager. To update the database you need to run this command `lensfun-update-data` as root.

Comment: Well, that's *half true*. ;) The command [may be run as root, but doesn't need to be](https://www.mankier.com/1/lensfun-update-data). It should also be noted that it requires python3, and that many Linux distros don't include it in the base Lensfun package, but in an additional package named "lensfun-tools" or similar. Also, saying a given lens is "probably" available in an update is a bit of a stretch... it may or may not be. Check that [here](https://wilson.bronger.org/lensfun_coverage.html).

Feel free to work this information into your answer. :)

Comment: When running without root: it stores the files to `~/.local/share/lensfun/update`.  However, I had to move (or sym-link) the xml files one level up (i.e. to `~/.local/share/lensfun`), otherwise the new lenses where not available in Darktable.  Not sure if this is an issue of lensfun or of Darktable.  Credit for this goes to [Victor Klos](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/70010/38328).